# Degree of $\mathbb C(t)$ as a field extension over $\mathbb C$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Is it true that for an indeterminate $t$, $\mathbb C(t)$ is a field extension over $\mathbb C$ of uncountable degree? Why or why not?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that the elements $1/(t-\alpha)$ are independent as $\alpha$ runs through the complex numbers?

Comment: Ah I see. For each finite subset of these functions, the linear independence equation and Hausdorffness imply that there exists an open ball around each alpha such that the corresponding function must be bounded, making its coefficient zero. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Using the comment from @GerryMyerson)

> The set $\{1 /(t-λ): λ ∈ ℂ\}$ is infinite and linearly independent in $ℂ(t)$

Suppose that $λ_{1}, …, λ_{d}$ are distinct and $α_{1}, …, α_{d} ∈ ℂ$ are such that
$$
α_{1} \frac{1}{t-λ_{1}}+⋯+α_{d} \frac{1}{t-λ_{d}}=0
$$
Multiplying up we get
$$
p(t):=\sum_{i=1}^{d} α_{i} \prod_{j ≠ i}\left(t-λ_{j}\right)=0 .
$$
However $\prod_{j ≠ i}\left(λ_{i}-λ_{j}\right) ≠ 0$ since the $λ_{i}$’s are distinct and $0=p\left(λ_{i}\right)=α_{i} \prod_{j ≠ i}\left(λ_{i}-λ_{j}\right)$, so $α_{i}=0$ for all $1 ⩽ i ⩽ d$. The claim follows.