# Degree of a field extension over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, transcendence-degree

I am supposed to find the degree of $ \mathbb {Q} (\sqrt3) \bigcap \mathbb {Q} (i)$ over  $\mathbb{C}$.

My approach: Disclaimer: not sure how to go over $\mathbb{C}$.

The minimal poly of $ \mathbb {Q} (\sqrt3) $ is $x^2 - 3 = 0$. Hence, $ \mathbb {Q} (\sqrt3) $ is of degree 2. The minimal poly of $ \mathbb {Q} (i) $ is $x^2 + 1 = 0$. So, $ \mathbb {Q} (i) $ is of degree 2. Thus, because of multiplicativity of field extensions $[ℂ:ℚ(√3)∩ℚ()] = 4$.

P.S. I found [Degree of C(t) as a field extension over C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199293/degree-of-ct-as-a-field-extension-over-c), but I think it is irrelevant.

Comment: Corrected now. Sorry.

Comment: I think the degree over $\Bbb Q$ is meant. A popular question is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645371/is-it-true-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-cap-mathbbqi-mathbbq), and yours has the same answer. So the degree is $1$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I can go from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q} \Q \subseteq \Q(\sqrt3) \cap \Q(i) \subseteq \Bbb R \cap \Q(i) = \Q$, we have
$$
\Q(\sqrt3) \cap \Q(i) = \Q.
$$
Then
$$
[\Bbb C : \Q(\sqrt3) \cap \Q(i)] = [\Bbb C : \Q] = \infty.
$$